# Show that a complete metric space without isolated points is uncountable

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I've seen a few questions already posted on here, but they all deal with perfect subsets and being Hausdorff, both of which are topics we haven't covered yet.

I know that a point a is isolated if $\{a\}$ is open (aka there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B_{\epsilon}(a) = \{a\}$.  I am supposed to consider singletons and then use Baire Category Theorem.

Could someone help me with where to start?

Comment: Which part of Baire's theorem would singletons fit?

Comment: Leaving a comment because this is essentially the same as the accepted answer but uses BCT in (what I think is) a more direct way: Enumerate $X$ as $\{x_n : n \in \Bbb N\}$. Then, each $\{x_n\}$ is closed since $X$ is a metric space. Assume that no point is isolated. Thus, each $\{x_n\}$ has empty interior. But we also have $X = \bigcup_n \{x_n\}$, which is a contradiction as we have written a nonempty complete metric space as a countable union of closed, interior-less sets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Hint.* Let $(X;d)$ be a (nonempty) complete metric space with no isolated points.

Suppose $X$ is countable and fix an enumeration $X = \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$. For each $x \in X$ let $O_x := X \setminus \{x\}$.

Show that, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $O_{x_n}$ is dense in $(X;d)$.

By the Baire Category Theorem this implies that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} O_{x_n}$ is dense in $(X;d)$. Now figure out why this is a contradiction.

Comment: Is each $O_{x_n}$ dense because its a complete set with an open ball removed?  For the contradiction part, is it because then  $O_{x_n}^c$ is hollow so the union of the  $O_{x_n}$s would also be hollow, but the union of them is X, which is complete and therefore not hollow?

Comment: If $O_{x_n}$ where the entire space with an open ball removed, it certainly wouldn't be dense... I also don't know what 'hollow' means in this context.

Comment: So then how do I show that $O_{x_n}$ is dense? Hollow means has empty interior

Comment: Write down the definition of 'dense'. Observe that $(X;d)$ having no isolated points implies that for each $x \in X$ the set $X \setminus \{x\}$ is dense (for any one $x \in X$ you actually only need that $x$ is not an isolated point of $(X;d)$). And now that I know what 'hollow' means - the second part of your argument also needs some work.

Comment: could you give a hint as to what to do for the final part?  I don't really get what the sets $O_{x_n}$ are

Comment: Their intersection would be X minus all of its points so it should be hollow?

Comment: The intersection would be $X$ minus of all its points, correct. So it would be empty. Can the empty set be dense in $X$?

Answer (score 3):

Say $(X,d)$ is a countable complete metric space without isolated points. 
Then, we can write $X=\{x_n :n \geq 1 \}$(as we assume it is countable). 
Now, consider the Sets $U_n= X \backslash \{x_n\}$. Since $\{x_n \}$ is closed,
$U_n $ is open. Also because $\{ x_n \}$ is not isolated(as given), for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $B(x_n,\varepsilon) \cap U_n \neq \phi$, Hence $U_n$ is dense in $X$(Any other point not equal to $X$ already in $U_n$ ). 
Now, by Baire's Category Theorem $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} U_n$ is dense in $X$. But since  $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} U_n \neq \phi$ is a contradiction so our assumption that $X$ is countable is not true hence, $X$ must by uncountable.

---

---

[Stefan Meskan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/217623/stefan-mesken) also explains up to this point in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523804/760990). Only point need to reconsider is why $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} U_n \neq \phi$ is contradiction. 
Let's consider a general case for $X$
Since $\mathbb{X}$ is countable we can write $\mathbb{X}=\{x_1,x_2,x_3 \dots,x_{n-1} x_n \}: 
 n \in \mathbb{N} $ & as we defined $$U_1=\{\hphantom{x_1,}x_2,x_3,x_4 \dots,x_{n-1}, x_n\}$$
$$U_2=\{x_1,\hphantom{x_2,}x_3,x_4 \dots,x_{n-1}, x_n\}$$ $$U_3=\{x_1,x_2,\hphantom{x_3},x_4 \dots,x_{n-1}, x_n\} $$  $$\vdots \hphantom{U_4 = \{ x1x2} \vdots \hphantom{ \},\{ } \vdots \hphantom{ \},\{ } \vdots \hphantom{ \},\{ } \vdots  $$
$$ U_n=  \{ x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \dots x_{n-1},\hphantom{x_n}     \}$$

So, cleary $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} U_n = \phi$. (As $\forall x_n \in X \hspace{0.2cm} \exists \hspace{0.2cm} U_n \text{ and  } \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_n=X$)