Completeness Cardinality
I am working with metric spaces and encountered the following problem:
Problem: Prove that a complete metric space $M$ without isolated points has cardinality at least $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.
What I have so far:

To not have isolated points, a complete metric space must obviously have infinite cardinality (otherwise the topology would be discrete). Therefore, $|M|\geq \aleph_0 = |\mathbb{N}|$
Since the space is complete, I have tried to relate the cardinality of $|M|$ with that of the succesions over $|M|$, which is greater or equal to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ because of the former point.

I was also considering using Baire's theorem to approach this problem, but I’m not sure how to connect the dots.
Any guidance or references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
P.S: A corollary to this exercise, if someone wants to answer it as well, would be:
Corollary: Deduce from the previous that an infinite, complete, and separable metric space has exactly cardinality $ \aleph_0 $ or $ 2^{\aleph_0} $.
Where we already know that a separable, metric space has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ at most.

This follows from baires theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523793/show-that-a-complete-metric-space-without-isolated-points-is-uncountable

So it's a duplicate then
